# Difference between onDisabled() and onDeleted() of AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android

I was reading `AppWidgetProvider` on [developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) but I am confused in difference between `onDisabled()` and `onDeleted()`.
 Could someone please make it clear or give any example/resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in docs, that you linked:

> onDisabled...
>   Called in response to the ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED broadcast, which is sent when the last AppWidget instance for this provider is deleted. Override this method to implement your own AppWidget functionality.
>
> onDeleted...
>   Called in response to the ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED broadcast when one or more AppWidget instances have been deleted. Override this method to implement your own AppWidget functionality.

So, if you, for example have two instances of widget placed on your homescreen and you deleted first instance, then onDeleted will be called. When you will delete second instance onDeleted and onDisabled will be called.